# iOS archive validation started to fail after upgrading Cordova library to 7.0.1. ( No Image found under key `CFBundleIcons` AppIcon40x40)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

[image]**Cordova ( 7.0.1 ) Plugin Details**

```
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.7.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.2 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-screen-orientation 2.0.0 "Screen Orientation"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.2 "Whitelist"
es6-promise-plugin 4.1.0 "Promise"
```

**Things I have already tried**

- Tried removing and adding iOS platform.
- Removed the CarPlay
- Removed the `CFBundleIcons` from the **info.plist**.
- Manually added all the icons under **Build Phases> Copy Bundle Resources**.
- Removed all the icons from the `images.xcassest` and manually dragged and dropped them back.

I'm using common icon for both iOS and Android application, that being said, I have only one entry in my `config.xml`

i.e `<icon src="www/img/icon.png" />`.

Also I'm not using **ionic**.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason why you aren’t specifying each required icon size in your config.xml? The documentation is wrong when it suggests a single icon is sufficient for iOS (I have an issue assigned to me, so docs will get updated as soon as I get a spare moment)

Comment: @KerriShotts It was all working fine before I upgraded the Cordova to 7.0.1 with the single icon. Has the recent update changed how Cordova generates icons for iOS ? I fixed the issue using `cordova-icon` plugin to generate the images and then manually dragged them to the `xcassest.images`.